# Data Frame Row Value Correlation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, correlation

How do I find the correlation between the following fields for each row value in the Product_Code column based on the following df?

I have already tried df.corr() with no success.

The actual data frame is 2mm+ rows. Sample data frame below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame{ ‘Company_Numb’: ["125", "137", "129"],
'Year' : [“2016”, ”2017”, “2018”],'Product_Code' : [“Batteries”, “Clothes”, “Tablet”],'Sales_Success_Code' : [0, 1, 0],‘Peer_Group_Rank’ : [65.65, 41.24, 16.12],‘Store_Count’ : [5, 14, 2],‘Employee_Count’ : [74, 19, 10]}
```

•   What is the correlation between Sales_Success_Code and  Peer_Group_Rank for each product code

•   What is the correlation between Sales_Success_Code and Store_Count for each product code

•   What is the correlation between Sales_Success_Code and Employee_count for each product code

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

I used the same code as yours and got the result. Just initialized the pandas object and that's it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Company_Numb': ["125", "137", "129"],
                   'Year': ['2016', '2017', '2018'], 'Product_Code': ['Batteries', 'Clothes', 'Tablet'], 'Sales_Success_Code': [0, 1, 0], 'Peer_Group_Rank': [65.65, 41.24, 16.12], 'Store_Count': [5, 14, 2], 'Employee_Count': [74, 19, 10]})

print(df.corr())

#OUTPUT:
                   Employee_Count     ...       Store_Count
Employee_Count            1.000000     ...         -0.150210
Peer_Group_Rank           0.920429     ...          0.248218
Sales_Success_Code       -0.383280     ...          0.970725
Store_Count              -0.150210     ...          1.000000
```

Comment: Robex, I was able to get to that point; however, I am trying to find the correlation for each Product_Code. So column zero of the output would read: 'Batteries', 'Clothes', 'Tablet'. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to find a correlation of a single item in the list. Correlation in itself is used the measure the changes between two vectors. It's because of how the Pearson formula calculates correlation with the standard deviation and covariances of the two vectors.
However, there is a solution to finding the correlation coefficient of an individual column with relation to another column.

```
print(df.Sales_Success_Code.corr(df.Peer_Group_Rank))
```